# What is the meaning of a "permutation -invariant " MHV amplitude?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, scattering, lorentz-symmetry

When reading my notes, I read that the difference between 4 points colour-ordered MHV amplitude and gravitational MHV amplitude is that the gravitational MHV amplitude is permutation-invariant, unlike the latter.

*I don't understand what this means.* **Is it that when calculating the MHV amplitude I am not meant to take the permutations into consideration?**

**Does this mean that, using a 3-point diagram as an example to measure the MHV amplitude we would start by only considering:**

[image]

$$A= \sqrt2 \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 \epsilon_3 p_1 $$

**instead of the "correct" $A$?:**
$$A= \sqrt 2 \left( \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 \epsilon_3 p_1 +\epsilon_2 \epsilon_3 \epsilon_1 p_2+\epsilon_3 \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 p_3\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

By little group scaling, the three-particle MHV amplitude for three massless spin-1 particles is given by
$$ \mathcal{M}^{--+} =\frac{\langle 12 \rangle^3}{\langle 13 \rangle\langle 32 \rangle}~.$$
This is not permutation invariant in the sense that if I exchange legs one and two I pick up a minus sign. The equivalent graviton amplitude doesn't pick up a minus sign, since it is squared, and hence *is* permutation invariant.

An interesting side note, the amplitude above violates bose symmetry, which can only be cured if the coupling constant also picks up a minus sign under the exchange: the amplitude above *must* be for colour charged spin-1 particles (gluons) and must vanish for photons.